# Semigroup where the Binary Operation is not Associative.

Tags: binary-operations, associativity

I am working on my functional composition, which has the associative property, to show if a given pair is a semigroup or not. I believe all Semigroups have to have a binary operation that is associative.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is part of the definition of a semigroup.

Comment: Ok thank you! Didn't know if there were any special cases.

Comment: Without the requirement that a binary operation be *associative*, the structure closed under a binary operation is called a [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)).  This is more general than a semigroup, not a special case of semigroups.

Answer (score 2):

> In mathematics, a semigroup is an algebraic structure consisting of a set together with an associative binary operation

-[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup), 2015

If you're interested in a set with a not-necessarily-associative binary operation, you're looking for a "magma".

Comment: Thank you, I am learning this, so wanted quick reassurance from some better mathematicians.

Comment: Ok, I have read about them, but our course has yet to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

Associativity is part of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Definition) of semigroup, so yes, all semigroups are associative.

If you need to show that some set with an operation on it is a semigroup, though, you can't take it for granted. You must instead show that the operation is defined for every pair of elements and that it is indeed associative.

Comment: Ok, this is where I need to look into this further!